# Table Formatting Correctly on Laptop...Phone won't resize table with animated gif

Tags: wordpress, conditional-formatting

Website is www.lionofjudahworldwide.com

Click on buy incense

On laptop table sizes correctly..

On phone animated gif is outside bounds...

Here is code

Table A

```
<p><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vWXK8yhFYm8" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
```

copied from inside youtube

Table B

```
<img src="http://s2.favim.com/orig/150513/aesthetic-grunge-hipster-pale-Favim.com-2728352.gif" width="500" height="281" class="alignnone size-medium" />
```

Comment: nevermind....in Table two height and width for animated gif i just put 100% automatically resized image correctly inside table...SCHWEET

Answer (score 0):

Please use width in %.

```
<p><iframe width="100%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vWXK8yhFYm8" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>

<img src="http://s2.favim.com/orig/150513/aesthetic-grunge-hipster-pale-Favim.com-2728352.gif" width="100%" height="281" class="alignnone size-medium" />
```

It will work.